# Cannot toggle TextView style dynamically

Tags: android, textview, android-styles, android-typeface

In my project, I need to toggle `TextView` style to `Normal` and `Bold`. Here is the code:

```
mTitleTextView.setTypeface(mTitleTextView.getTypeface(), letterItem.isRead() ? Typeface.NORMAL : Typeface.BOLD);
```

This works good when `TextView` is not bold. But when current state is bold, it doesn't return to normal state.

```
mTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, letterItem.isRead() ? Typeface.NORMAL : Typeface.BOLD);
```

Above line fixes the problem, but I have used custom font and passing null for current typeface removes the font.

Comment: mTitleTextView.setTypeface(mTitleTextView.getTypeface(),Typeface.NORMAL);
try mTitleTextView.invalidate();

Answer (score 1):

After tying for a while this works for me :

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.invalidate();
        if(isCliked){
            isCliked = false;
            Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "test.ttf");
            textView.setTypeface(face,Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
        else{
            Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "test.ttf");
            textView.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD);
            isCliked = true;
        }
        Log.i("MainActivity", "onClick: "+isCliked);
    }
});
```

the typeface will remain the same, and change only bold and normal

Comment: As I said in my question, passing null for first argument, removes custom font.

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi I Update my answer please see, I've tried it and it works.